# Meta-Function to get the first template of a list of templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

Using the following metafunction `front` to get the first type of a typelist I try to write a similar metafunction to extract the first template of a list of templates.

```
namescpace detail {
    template<typename L> struct front_impl;
    template<template<typename, typename...> typename L, typename F, typename... I>
    struct front_impl<L<F, I...>> {
        typedef F type;  
    };
}
template<typename L> struct front_impl;
template<template<typename, typename...> typename L, typename F, typename... I>
struct front_impl<L<F, I...>> {
    typedef F type;  
};
```

One can use this as follows:

```
template<typename... T>
struct List {
    inline static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(T);
};

using l1 = List<A, B, C>;
using f1 = front<l1>;
```

Now I try to do the same with a list of templates. Therefore I use a list of templates `TList`:

```
template<template<typename> typename... TT>
struct TList {
    inline static constexpr size_t size = sizeof...(TT);
};
```

and the metafunction `tfront`:

```
template<typename T> struct tfront;
template<template<typename> typename F, template<typename> typename... R>
struct tfront<TList<F, R...>> {
    template<typename T> using type = F<T>;
};
```

Then I can extract the first of a list of templates `A`, `B`, ... (not shown here):

```
    using tlist = TList<A, B, C>;

    template<typename T>
    using f = typename tfront<tlist>::template type<T>;

    f<int> xx;
```

Then `xx` ist of type `A<int>`.

*The Question is*: can I write the metafunction `tfront` in the same way as `front`, that is not as a partial specialization for the list of templates `TList` *but*  for every variadic template of templates? So I would like to introduce a parameter `L` for `tfront` as a template-template-parameter with a variadic list of templates, so that the compiler must also deduce the type of the type `L` as in the case of `front`.

I would like to write something like (but what to use as ???):

```
template<template<typename> typename F, ??? TL, template<typename> typename... R>
struct tfront<TL<F, R...>> {
    template<typename T> using type = F<T>;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra layer of `template<typename> typename...`:

```
template<typename>
struct tfront;

template<template<typename> typename F, 
         template<template<typename> typename...> typename TL, 
         template<typename> typename... R>
struct tfront<TL<F, R...>> 
{
};
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p02QVT4SlXnu6IoU)

Comment: Super! Is it possible to have the `front` metafunction for type-lists and the `tfront` for template-lists  *overload* each other: I mean can I have an additional specialization of `front` for template-lists? I think here concepts kick in?