# Metafunction to process a list of templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

In question [Meta-Function to get the first template of a list of templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775990/meta-function-to-get-the-first-template-of-a-list-of-templates) @vittorio-romeo gave the answer to write a meta-function to get the first template of a list of templates. Now I want to write a meta-funtion which accepts a template (as a metafunction) and a list of templates to process:

```
template<template<typename> typename F, 
         template<template<typename> typename...> typename TL> struct transform_T;
template<template<typename> typename F, 
         template<template<typename> typename...> typename TL,
         template<typename> typename... I>
struct transform_T<F, TL<I...>> {
};
```

But this definition doesn't compile: https://wandbox.org/permlink/CnY2DOGbAqW4Evq4

*Edit:*
With the change below it works. Here a complete example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename... T>
struct List {};

template<template<typename> typename... TT>
struct TList {};

template<template<template<typename> typename> typename F, 
         typename TL> struct transform_T;
template<template<template<typename> typename> typename F, 
         template<template<typename> typename...> typename TL,
         template<typename> typename... I>
struct transform_T<F, TL<I...>> {
    typedef List<typename F<I>::type...> type;                
};

template<typename>
struct A {};
template<typename>
struct B {};

using l1 = TList<A, B>;

template<template<typename> typename X>
struct F {
    typedef X<int> type;  
};

using l2 = typename transform_T<F, l1>::type;

l2::_; // List<A<int>, B<int>>

int main() {
}
```

My question ist still, we do I have to write only `typename TL` in the /primary/ template?

Comment: This error is saying `TL<I...>` is a type instead of a template. What you want to do though, is unclear

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear about what to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary template definition should match the specialization arguments:

```
template<template<typename> typename F1,typename TL> struct transform_T;
```

whether this is what you really want depends on the kind of "processing" you want to perform.

> My question ist still, we do I have to write only typename TL in the /primary/ template?

the primary template declares the template parameters of the given template name, that is, it tells the compiler that some name is a template and that its parameters are of the kind you specified ( type, non-type, template template parameters ... ).

A partial specialization declares a new set of template parameters to be matched to the primary ones via type deduction; clearly, their kind must match.

In your original code, you're passing `TL<I...>` ( that is a type ) to a parameter of template-template kind (`template<template<typename> typename...> typename TL`).

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear, but  I still do not fully understand why ...

Comment: Ok, my fault was to think of `l1` as of kind /template/ because it is a list of templates. But a list of templates is a concrete type ...